# Why do I get ResponseCode 0 using RestSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

I keep trying access this page with various working http proxies and I keep getting the response code 0

```
var c = new RestClient("https://api.myip.com");
c.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy.Split(":")[0], Convert.ToInt32(proxy.Split(":")[1]));
c.Timeout = 2000;
var req = new RestRequest("/", Method.GET);
var rest = c.Get(req);
```

I've checked the proxies, they are alive and working well.
Why am I getting the response code 0 for the majority of times? Or sometimes even TemporaryRedirect or BadRequest but that's very rare. I'd say 9.9/10 times I get the response code 0. And sometimes it works just fine but it's super rare.

Comment: Do you mean `StatusCode`? Is the response content otherwise what you expect?

Comment: What occurs when you hit that endpoint using Postman instead?

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, status code, my bad

Comment: @mjwills Can I use a proxy with postman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be checking some more stuff in the response you get. The `IRestResponse` instance gives you quite a lot of information about what happened. RestSharp doesn't throw exceptions by design and any errors that occurred during the request execution would result in the response code `0` and the exception itself is added to the response object.

We have [documented this behaviour](https://restsharp.dev/get-help/faq.html#empty-response). There are a bunch of other properties that you can use to find out the actual response code and any errors.

You can also set the client `ThrowOnAnyError` property to `true` to force RestSharp to throw.