# Getting System.Exception 0:

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have a method that seems to be throwing a "System.Excpetion 0: " without any message. This exception is happening in the production code as seen from the logs but I can't replicate it so far in my local environment. Looks like it comes from RestSharp RestClient(string url) where I've tried an invalid url and a correct url but nothing has replicated such exception yet.

endpoint.url is just a string to hold the base url
endpoint.endpoint is remaining part of the url for the get endpoint i want to hit
endpoint.basicAuth

stack trace says it comes from line 238:

```
        238: var client = new RestClient(endpoint.url);
        var request = new RestRequest(endpoint.endpoint, Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(": " + endpoint.basicAuthToken)));

        var response = client.Execute(request);

        if(response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            throw new Exception(message: response.StatusCode.ToString());
        }

        string contentString = response.Content.ToString();
```

Comment: "throwing a "System.Excpetion 0: " without any message or other helpful details.:  Can you show a bit more code, and also the 'unhelpful details" ?  Like how is this class `endpoint` defined? and some other details that are in [mre].  With the info you gave so far, no one is interested in line no #238.

Comment: With this being related to work I there are some things I cannot provide so hopefully in my recent edits it can help answer your questions.

Comment: Ok, while [they](https://restsharp.dev/get-help/) say: "Please do not use GitHub issues to ask question about using RestSharp.", that should not stop your from searching the issues on Github. When you did you could have found: [Exceptions are not thrown, response with status code 0 returned](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1379)

Comment: Yes, thank you. I think I was just so thrown off by seeing System.Excpetion: 0 and not having anything being thrown from RestSharp I sort of veered of path.

Comment: Ok, but search is a very powerfull thing, so you could also have said [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62272498/why-do-i-get-responsecode-0-using-restsharp) is not providing a solution too.. 

Answer (score 0):

A client.Execute(request) with a invalid url is getting {"The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."} therefore the IRestReponse returned has a StatusCode property of 0 and when catching this exception to print out its excpetion message 'throw new Exception(message: response.StatusCode.ToString());' it writes what I'm seeeig of "System.Exception: 0"